# Log-in to Website

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I'm trying to create an Excel macro that will log me into [this website](https://www.prudential.com/login). I've written macros to log me into to other websites, but this one is somehow different.

When I use the following code to programmatically insert the username and password and then programmatically click the "log-in" button, the webpage comes back with the message

> Error: please provide a username and Error: Please provide a
>   password

```
Sub LogIn()
' Open IE and navigate to the log-in page    
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.prudential.com/login"

' Loop until the page is fully loaded
        Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.ReadyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))

' Enter the necessary information on the Login web page and click the submit button
        ie.document.getElementById("username").Value = "abcdef"
        ie.document.getElementById("password").Value = "12345678"
        ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary btn-login btn-sm-block analytics-login")(0).Click

' Loop until the page is fully loaded
        Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.ReadyState = 4
             DoEvents
        Loop
    End With

' Do stuff

' Quit IE
    ie.Quit
End Sub
```

I can see that my code has inserted the username and password into the webpage boxes, but for some reason after successfully clicking the submit button, the username and password are not being detected.

What code will successfully insert the username and password so that it can be processed by the web page?  **You'll know that your code works when you get the following error message:**

> We are unable to verify your username and password. Please try again.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

It actually wants you to send a key, so you can bypass this request like this:

```
ie.document.getElementById("username").Focus
ie.document.getElementById("username").Value = "abcde"
Application.SendKeys "f", True

ie.document.getElementById("password").Focus
ie.document.getElementById("password").Value = "1234567"
Application.SendKeys "8", True

ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary btn-login btn-sm-block analytics-login")(0).Click
```

**Edit:**

```
Sub GetData()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim desc As IHTMLElement
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    With ie
        .navigate "https://www.prudential.com/login"
        .Visible = True
    End With

    Do While (ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE)
        DoEvents
    Loop

    ie.document.getElementById("username").Focus
    Application.SendKeys "abcdef"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

    ie.document.getElementById("password").Focus
    Application.SendKeys "12345678"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

    ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary btn-login btn-sm-block analytics-login")(0).Click

    Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I get a run-time error 70 permission denied when I execute the sendkeys line as you've written it.  If I write application.sendkeys, then I still get the Error: please provide a username" and "Error: Please provide a password.  Did the code actually work for you?

Comment: Strange, it runs smoothly for me. I will check.

Comment: @ron can you try the full code? Also revised Application.SendKeys for you. Please let us know.

Comment: I still get the Error: please provide a username" and "Error: Please provide a password.

Comment: @ron Obviously when you trigger the code by clicking Log In button, it does not recognize the values which you set to the inputs. How about completely forgetting about setting its value and simulating the entry of the whole username and password? Please check the edited code.

Comment: Still no luck, nothing was inserted.

Comment: @ron What version is your excel?

Comment: @ron It might sound silly but can you assign this sub to a button and try to run it from that button?

Comment: I'm running Excel 2002

Comment: @ron Unfortunately [Sendkeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278655(v=office.15).aspx) for Excel 2002, 2003 and 2007 are not supported. You should have Excel 2010 or higher to be able to run Sendkeys. Since you have to physically input username and password, you are going to need Sendkeys for this specific website.

Comment: @ron A quick internet search says that you need to turn off Window's UAC for Sendkeys to work if you are running it on a unsupported version of Excel. Good luck.

Comment: @Tehscript I understand sendkeys but how did you know to use "f" and "8"  please?

Comment: @QHarr Suppose that your username is "abcdef". When you assign it to ie.document.getElementById("username"), it accepts the username but it does not trigger because you physically need to enter it. So you can use any combination of "abcdef". Either enter "abcdef" as a whole word using sendkeys, or assign "abc" and then enter "def" using sendkeys, or assign "abcd" and then enter "ef" using sendkeys. It doesn't matter. It doesn't specifically need to be "f". I did it because it was sufficient to finalise it with sendkeys.

Comment: Thank you. Interesting example.

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE       As Long = 4
Const URL_String                As String = "https://www.prudential.com/login"

Sub Login()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim ObjElement As Object

    ' using Late Binding
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
        .navigate URL_String
        .Visible = True
    End With

    Do While (IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE)
        DoEvents
    Loop

    IE.document.getElementByid("username").Value = "abcdef"
    IE.document.getElementByid("password").Value = "12345678"

    ' Optional: I didn't need the wait time
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

    Set ObjElement = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary btn-login btn-sm-block analytics-login")
    ObjElement(0).Click

    Set IE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: This is essentially the code I am running.  Which error message do you receive back from the webpage, "Error: please provide a username" and "Error: Please provide a password" or "We are unable to verify your username and password. Please try again"?

Comment: @ron the second one

Comment: Hmmm...When I run your code I get the first error message.

Comment: @ron tried again now, it's the first. Strange, it's something with the site, the exact same code works very nice on another site.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach might be something like the following.

```
Sub Get_Logged_In()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, HTML As HTMLDocument
    Dim post As Object, elem As Object

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.prudential.com/login"
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set HTML = .document
    End With

    With HTML
        Set post = .querySelector("#username")
        post.Focus
        post.innerText = "abcdef"

        Set elem = .querySelector("#password")
        elem.Focus
        elem.innerText = "12345678"

        .querySelector("button[data-qa='Login Button']").Click
    End With
    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Reference to add to the library:

```
1. Microsoft Internet Controls
2. Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

Comment: This method worked, thank you! Could you please add some explanation to your answer about what method this is and why it works? For example, how do you know when to use "Set post" vs.   "Set elem"? Thanks again for an excellent approach!

Comment: `post` and `elem` are two variables. I have defined those variables so that I can reuse them more than once. However, the above approach looks slightly different because I've used `.querySelector()` instead of `.getelementbyid()`. They both do the same thing. If you like you can use that like `set post = .getelementbyid("username") ` and so on. One last thing: I tried to show a cleaner approach that is why I used `with block` twice in my code, it's not necessary, though. Hope that helps.

Comment: How do I "quit" IE after I pass the End With (HTML) line?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has a similar problem I was finally able to get Sendkeys to work. Still, if anyone can come up with a non-Sendkeys solution it would be much preferred.

Two important points in getting Sendkeys to work are 1) use of

```
    Set WSS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
```

and 2) to be sure to run the macro from Excel (*e.g.* tools-macro-macros) and **not** from the VB Editor (running from the editor will simply insert the text somewhere within the code and not on the target webpage).

```
' Open IE and navigate to the log-in page
    Application.StatusBar = "Opening IE and logging in to the website"

    Set WSS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    my_username = "abcdef"
    my_pw = "12345678"

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.prudential.com/login"
        .Top = 0
        .Left = 0
        .Height = 1025
        .Width = 1925

' Loop until the page is fully loaded
        Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.ReadyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))        
        WSS.SendKeys "{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}"
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

        WSS.SendKeys my_username
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        WSS.SendKeys "{TAB}"
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        WSS.SendKeys my_pw
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")

        ie.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary btn-login btn-sm-block analytics-login")(0).Click

' Loop until the page is fully loaded
        Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.ReadyState = 4
             DoEvents
        Loop
    End With

' You're now logged in, do your stuff..
```